# throw an access denied in a popup rom controller using symfony3

Tags: symfony, access-denied

Hey so i'm building a symfony web application, and i have a function that check whether the current user have the permission to do the controller action or not

```
$controle = $this->get('Controles');
if(($controle->is_Granted('Paramétrage point de vente','Paramétrage',$this->getUser()))==false){
         throw new AccessDeniedException();
}
```

But it throw an 403 Access Denied error page and i want it to be in a popup so i tried using the getFlashBag method

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag('Warning', 'You are not allowed to do that');
```

but the browser displays this :

```
The connection has been reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loaded.
```

Does anyone know why or maybe any other method to throw a popup instead of the exception?

Here is my full controller

```
class PointVenteController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $session = new Session();
        $session->set('module', 'Paramétrage');
        $session->set('page', 'Gestion des points de vente');
        $session->set('menu', 'Parametrage-menu.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/pointVente", name="pointVente_index",
     * defaults={"_risque" ="Paramétrage","_icon" = "fa fa-wrench", "_titre" = "Paramétrage point de vente", "_type" = "L", "_partie" = "Point de vente"  })
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('Warning', 'You are not allowed to do that');
        $controle = $this->get('Controles');
        if(($controle->is_Granted('Paramétrage point de vente','Paramétrage',$this->getUser()))==false){throw new AccessDeniedException('You are not allowed to do that !!');}
        $datatable = $this->get('app.datatable.Bureau');
        $datatable->buildDatatable();
        return $this->render('ParamBundle:Parametrage:PointVente/index.html.twig',array(
            'datatable' =>$datatable,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: to add a flash message you have to do : $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('Warning', 'You are not allowed to do that');

Comment: I fixed it but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you show us your full controller ?

Comment: Sure, i've updated my post